# Using array of symbols in model delegate declaration

Tags: ruby

I am trying to dynamically pass some values to `delegate` in my model. I have the parameters as an array of symbols:

```
[:first_name,
:first_name=,
:last_name,
:last_name=,
:email,
:email=]
```

How can I use this? `Array#join` converts each of my elements to a string which is no good. I need to include the array above like this:

```
delegate   <ARRAY-OF-SYMBOLS-HERE,
           to: :my_other_class
           prefix: :my_prefix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass your array directly into `delegate` method:

```
delegate symbols_array, to: :my_other_class, prefix: :my_prefix
```

Comment: no need `splat(*)`. [`delegate()`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) accept array as argument `delegate(*methods)` . So `delegate(*symbols_array)` same as `delegate(symbols_array)`

Comment: @Зелёный you're right. Thanks for your suggestion. You're not so green as you claim to be. :)

Comment: I'm getting an error here: `undefined method `to_sym' for [:attribute_1, :attribute_2]:Array`